# Reading or encoding metadata from a .bin file

Tags: python, encoding, binary, metadata, file-read

I have a binary file containing metadata; what are the options for reading such files?
And when i open it using Notepad++ this is what I got,
[image]

I tried to change the encoding but i got no results